# How can I provide template specializations for typedefs of the same type?

Tags: c++, templates, c-preprocessor, typedef

A 3rd party SDK defines several typedefs, e.g.:

```
typedef unsigned char SDK_BYTE
typedef double SDK_DOUBLE
typedef unsigned char SDK_BOOLEAN
```

It also defines a variant type SdkVariant:

```
class SdkVariant
{
public:
    enum SdkType { SdkByte, SdkDouble, SdkBoolean };
    bool toByte(SDK_BYTE&);
    bool toDouble(SDK_DOUBLE&);
    bool toBool(SDK_BOOLEAN&);
    SdkType type();
};
```

Retrieving a value from such a variant looks like this (presuming, we know the type of the contained value):

```
SdkVariant variant(foobar());
double value;
bool res = variant.toDouble(value);
if (!res)
    diePainfully();
else
    doSomethingWith(value);
```

This is quite verbose and therefore I want to provide a variant_cast-function-class that can perform the value retrieval and error handling:

```
// general interface:
template<class T>
class variant_cast
{
public:
    T operator()(const SdkVariant& variant);
};

// template specializations:
template<>
SDK_DOUBLE variant_cast<SDK_DOUBLE>::operator()(const SdkVariant& variant)
{
    SDK_DOUBLE value;
    bool res = variant.toDouble(value);
    if (!res)
        diePainfully();
    return value;
}

template<>
SDK_BYTE variant_cast<SDK_BYTE>::operator()(const SdkVariant& variant)
{
    SDK_BYTE value;
    bool res = variant.toByte(value);
    if (!res)
        diePainfully();
    return value;
}

template<>
SDK_BOOLEAN variant_cast<SDK_BOOLEAN>::operator()(const SdkVariant& variant)
{
    SDK_BOOLEAN value;
    bool res = variant.toByte(value);
    if (!res)
        diePainfully();
    return value;
}
```

This does not compile (C2995: Function template already defined), because SDK_BYTE and SDK_BOOLEAN are the same types (unsigned char). My idea is now to let the preprocessor check that SDK_BYTE and SDK_BOOLEAN are the same and if so, define a single template specialization for both. If they're different, it should use the two separate specializations from above. Like this:

```
#if SDK_BYTE == SDK_BOOLEAN
template<>
SDK_BYTE variant_cast<SDK_BYTE>::operator()(const SdkVariant& variant)
{
    SDK_BYTE value;
    bool res;
    if (variant.type() == SdkByte)
        res = variant.toByte(value);
    else
        res = variant.toBool(value);
    if (!res)
        diePainfully();
    return value;
}
#else
    // code from above
#endif
```

The problem with the above code is, that it appears to be impossible for the preprocessor to resolve the two typedefs. Is there a way to compare two typedefs (correctly) during preprocessing? If not, is there a way to hinder the compiler from resolving the typedefs, so that it would accept two different template specializations for SDK_BYTE and SDK_BOOLEAN? If not, I can still provide the single template specialization and use BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT to make the compiler fail if SDK_BYTE and SDK_BOOLEAN are unequal, but is there a better way to solve my problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, the preprocessor does not understand `typedefs`.

Comment: [`BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/boost/strong_typedef.hpp)

Comment: Could you use C++11 and `std::enable_if`, combined with `std::is_same`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If C++11 is an option for you, here is some code illustrating a possible solution using `std::enable_if` and `std::is_same`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct SdkVariant
{
};

typedef int   type1;
typedef float type2;

template <typename T, typename Enable=void>
class variant_cast
{
public:
  /* Default implementation of the converter. This is undefined, but
     you can define it to throw an exception instead. */
  T operator()(const SdkVariant &v);
};

/* Conversion for type1. */
template <typename T>
class variant_cast<T,typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T,type1>::value>::type>
{
public:
  type1 operator()(const SdkVariant &v)
  {
    return type1 { 0 };
  }
};

/* Conversion for type2, IF type2 != type1. Otherwise this
   specialization will never be used. */
template <typename T>
class variant_cast<T,typename std::enable_if<
         std::is_same<T,type2>::value
      && !std::is_same<type1,type2>::value>::type>
{
 public:
  type2 operator()(const SdkVariant &v)
  {
    return type2 { 1 };
  }
};

int main()
{
  variant_cast<type1> vc1;
  variant_cast<type2> vc2;
  std::cout << vc1({}) << std::endl;
  std::cout << vc2({}) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

A few notes:

1. Instead of the various types you get defined by that library, I have only defined `type1` and `type2`
2. I have defined an empty `SdkVariant` struct as a dummy
3. Because that dummy is empty, my conversion does not really convert anything. It just outputs a constant (value 0) when converting to `type1`, and a constant (value 1) when converting to `type2` (if `type2` is actually different from `type1`).
4. To test whether it does what you need, you may replace the definition of `type2` with

   ```
   typedef int type2;
   ```

   so it is identical with the definition for `type1`. It will still compile, and there will be no error related to any double definition.
5. I have tested this using GCC 4.7.0 and the `--std=c++11` option.

---

**Remark about the use of `std::enable_if` and partial vs. explicit template specializations**

The converter for `type1` is declared as

```
template <typename T>
variant_cast<T,typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T,type1>::value>::type>
```

which means it is defined *for any type `T` that is the same as `type1`*. Instead, we could have used an explicit specialization

```
template <>
variant_cast<type1>
```

which is much simpler, and **works, too**.

The only reason I didn't do that is that **in the case of `type2` it won't work**, because for `type2` we must check whether it is the same as `type1`, i.e. we must use `std::enable_if`:

```
template <>
class variant_cast<type2,
   typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<type1,type2>::value>::type>
```

Unfortunately, you can't use `std::enable_if` in an explicit specialization, because an explicit specialization is not a template – it's a real data type, and the compiler must process it. If `type1` and `type2` are identical, this:

```
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<type1,type2>::value>::type
```

does not exist, because of the way `std::enable_if` works. So the compilation fails because it can't instantiate this data type.

By defining the converter *for any type `T` that is the same as `type2`* we avoid the explicit instantiation for `type2`, hence we don't force the compiler to process it. It will only process the template specialization for `type2` if the `std::enable_if<...>::type` actually exists. Otherwise it will simply ignore it, which is exactly what we want.

Again, in the case of `type1` (and for any further `type3`, `type4` etc.) an explicit instantiation will work.

I think it's worthwhile pointing out that defining a template specialization *for any type `T` that is the same as some type `type`* is a **trick that is generally applicable** whenever you can't use an explicit specialization for formal reasons, so you use a partial specialization, but you really want to bind it to this one type only. For instance, a member template cannot be explicitly instantiated unless its enclosing template is explicitly instantiated, too. Using a combination of `std::enable_if` and `std::is_same` probably helps there, too.

Comment: Xeos approach actually works for both cases, SDK_BOOLEAN == SDK_BYTE and SDK_BOOLEAN != SDK_BYTE. Xeo, if you post that as an answer, I'll accept it. Otherwise, I'll answer the question myself with a code sample...

Comment: The above code does not specify template specializations for type1 and type2, so the original problem does not arise. If you'd specify template specializations, then the approach using enable_if/is_same would not compile. Template specializations for each type are required, because you must invoke the correct value-retrieval-function (toBool, toDouble, toByte) in the body. Also throwing means failing at run time. Failing at compile time is preferred.

Comment: @AlexanderTobiasHeinrich The two specializations of `variant_cast` are template specializations. The first one for `type1`, the second one for `type2`. They are partial specializations, not explicit specializations, but I don't see why that should be a problem. Regarding the exception: That is only there to cover types other than `type1` and `type2`. It's nothing to do with the fact that this is a solution to the original problem, and you can remove it if you want. The key mechanism (not re-defining the `type2`-specialization if `type1` is the same as `type2`) does work _at compile time_.

Comment: @AlexanderTobiasHeinrich What did you mean in your first comment about Xeos approach? The approach above also works for both cases.

Comment: I must apologize. I copied your code and played around with it for a while, and tried to add a third type to the game, but I did it wrong. Now that I looked into it again, I must admit, your solution does work and it is beautiful... accepted!

Comment: Great, thanks. I have added some more comments and further explanation. I have also removed the exception from the default definition of the converter; I think it was confusing, after all.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
SDK_BYTE asByte(SdkVariant & var)
{
  SDK_BYTE byte;
  bool const ok = var.toByte(byte);
  if (!ok) diePainfully();
  return byte;
}

SDK_DOUBLE asDouble(SdkVariant & var)
{
  SDK_DOUBLE d;
  bool const ok = var.toDouble(d);
  if (!ok) diePainfully();
  return d;
}

SDK_BOOLEAN asBoolean(SdkVariant & var)
{
  SDK_BOOLEAN b;
  bool const ok = var.toBool(b);
  if (!ok) diePainfully();
  return b;
}

static const bool byteAndBooleanAreTheSame = std::is_same<SDK_BYTE, SDK_BOOLEAN>::value;

template <bool b>
struct VariantCastImpl
{
  template <typename T> T cast(SdkVariant & var) const;

  template <> SDK_DOUBLE cast(SdkVariant & var) const { return asDouble(var); }
  template <> SDK_BYTE cast(SdkVariant & var) const { return asByte(var); }
  template <> SDK_BOOLEAN cast(SdkVariant & var) const { return asBoolean(var); }
};

template <>
struct VariantCastImpl<false>
{
  template <typename T> T cast(SdkVariant & var) const;

  template <> SDK_DOUBLE cast(SdkVariant & var) const { return asDouble(var); }
  template <> SDK_BYTE cast(SdkVariant & var) const
  {
    if (var.type() == SdkVariant::SdkByte)
    {
      return asByte(var);
    }
    else if (var.type() == SdkVariant::SdkBoolean)
    {
      return asBoolean(var);
    }
    else
    {
      diePainfully();
      return SDK_BYTE(); // dummy return, I assume diePainfully throws something
    }
  }
};

template <typename T>
T variant_cast(SdkVariant & var)
{
  return VariantCastImpl<!byteAndBooleanAreTheSame>().cast<T>(var);
};
```

Comment: Writing several specialized functions for the value retrieval is a valid approach, but eliminates the need for a template class. The first three functions (asByte, asDouble, asBoolean) would be enough.

Comment: You can use variant_cast<T> in generic code while you cannot do the same using the three asXXX-Functions. Other that that, I agree that just having the three functions will in general be enough to solve your problem. I have to admit that I considered your question a challenge, too ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just to be complete, using the BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF the code could look like this:

```
BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF(SDK_BYTE, mySDK_BYTE)
BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF(SDK_BOOLEAN, mySDK_BOOLEAN)

template<>
mySDK_BYTE variant_cast<mySDK_BYTE>::operator()(const SdkVariant& variant)
{
    SDK_BYTE value;
    bool res = variant.toByte(value);
    if (!res)
        diePainfully();
    return value;
}

template<>
mySDK_BOOLEAN variant_cast<mySDK_BOOLEAN>::operator()(const SdkVariant& variant)
{
    SDK_BOOLEAN value;
    bool res = variant.toByte(value);
    if (!res)
        diePainfully();
    return value;
}
```

This actually works. The only downside is, that for retrieving an `SDK_BOOLEAN` or `SDK_BYTE` one now has to write `variant_cast<mySDK_BOOLEAN>(myVariant)` or `variant_cast<mySDK_BYTE>(myVariant)`. Thanks Xeo.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be done with an unused template argument and an unused-but-unique struct declaration as the argument:

```
template<class T, class>
class variant_cast { /*...*/ };

template<>
SDK_BYTE variant_cast<SDK_BYTE, struct SDK_BYTE_XXX>::operator()/*...*/

template<>
SDK_BOOLEAN variant_cast<SDK_BOOLEAN, struct SDK_BOOLEAN_XXX>::operator()/*...*/
```