# Conditional explicit template instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Other than the preprocessor, how can I conditionally enable/disable explicit template instantiations?

Consider:

```
template <typename T> struct TheTemplate{ /* blah */ };

template struct TheTemplate<Type1>;
template struct TheTemplate<Type2>;
template struct TheTemplate<Type3>;
template struct TheTemplate<Type4>;
```

Under some compilation conditions, Type3 is the same as Type1 and Type4 is the same as Type2.  When this happens, I get an error.  I'd like to detect that the types are the same and not instantiate on Type3 and Type4 as in

```
// this does not work
template struct TheTemplate<Type1>;
template struct TheTemplate<Type2>;
template struct TheTemplate<enable_if<!is_same<Type1, Type3>::value, Type3>::type>;
template struct TheTemplate<enable_if<!is_same<Type2, Type4>::value, Type4>::type>;
```

I've diverted myself trying enable_if and SFINAE (and I believe I know why they fail), but only the preprocessor has worked (ugh).  I'm thinking about putting the types in a tuple or variadic, removing duplicates, and then use the remainder for instantiation.

Is there a way to conditionally enable/disable explicit template instantiation based on template argument types?

Comment: Is this a duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11982012/how-can-i-provide-template-specializations-for-typedefs-of-the-same-type

Comment: Does explicitly instantiating one class imply implicit instantiation of all base types?

Comment: @jogojapan - No, this explicit *instantiation* which is different from *specialization*.

Comment: In fact, why is repeated explicit instantiation an error?

Comment: @BenVoigt - I don't know if it should, but gcc 4.6.3 reports `error: duplicate explicit instantiation of ‘struct TheTemplate<Type3>’ [-fpermissive]`

Comment: BTW, looks like inheritance doesn't help here: "An explicit instantiation that names a class template specialization is also an explicit instantiation of the same kind (declaration or definition) of each of its members **(not including members inherited from base classes)** that has not been previously explicitly specialized"...

Comment: @BenVoigt it's an error for the same reason as multiple definitions of a function are an error: ODR violation. An explicit instantiation is not a template (with weak linkage), it's a class, so must only be defined once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
template <typename T> struct TheTemplate{ /* blah */ };

template<int> struct dummy { };

template struct TheTemplate<Type1>;
template struct TheTemplate<Type2>;
template struct TheTemplate<conditional<is_same<Type1, Type3>::value, dummy<3>, Type3>::type>;
template struct TheTemplate<conditional<is_same<Type2, Type4>::value, dummy<4>, Type4>::type>;
```

This still produces four explicit instantiations, but they won't be duplicates in the case where `Type3` is the same as `Type1` (unless `Type1` is `dummy<3>`!)

Comment: The downside is that `dummy` must meet the requirements of `TheTemplate` or the instantiation will give an error, so `dummy` might need to have members added to it, or you could write a partial specialization of `TheTemplate<dummy<N>>`

Comment: Alternatively, you can switch on the template that you instantiate: `template struct conditional<is_same<Type1, Type2>::value, details::TheTemplate<3>, TheTemplate<Type3>>::type::TheTemplate;`. By calling the `dummy` template `TheTemplate` too, the injected class name of one of its specializations is called `TheTemplate`, so that you in both cases can access `::type::TheTemplate` and instantiate whatever class type that is. Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/13332744/34509

Comment: @Johannes Nice, I didn't think of that

Comment: What is details:: in the example?

Comment: @gerardw, I think Johannes is suggesting replacing the `dummy` class template in my answer with `namespace details { template<int> struct TheTemplate { }; }` which is a different class template but with the same name